# Python: how to read 'Chunked Transfer Coding' from a request in web.py server

Tags: python, web.py

I am using `web.py` to run a server. I need to get a request from a remote server, however, the request sends me a data with Chunked Transfer Coding.

I can use `web.ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read(1000)` to get the data. But this is not what I need since I don't know the length of the data (because it is chunked). But if I use `web.ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read()` the server would crash.

Can anybody tell me how to get the chunked data in a request?

Comment: >But if I use web.ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read() the server would crash.  

How was it crashing? Throwing an exception/which one?

Answer (score 1):

Calling .read() will fetch the entire file into a string, which might be too large.

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140333/1125660

`while True:
    chunk = web.ctx.env['wsgi.input'].read(1000)
    if chunk == '':
        break
    process(chunk)`

Answer (score -1):

web.py runs CherryPy as the web server and it has support for handling requests with chunked transfer coding. Have you misread the documentation?