# What is a Pythonic way to detect that the next read will produce an EOF in Python 3 (and Python 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

Currently, I am using

```
def eofapproached(f):
    pos  = f.tell()
    near = f.read(1) == ''
    f.seek(pos)
    return near
```

to detect if a file open in 'r' mode (the default) is "at EOF" in the sense that the next `read` would produce the EOF condition.

I might use it like so:

```
f = open('filename.ext') # default 'r' mode

print(eofapproached(f))
```

FYI, I am working with some existing code that stops when EOF occurs, and I want my code to do some action just before that happens.

I am also interested in any suggestions for a better (e.g., more concise) function name. I thought of `eofnear`, but that does not necessarily convey as specific a meaning.

Currently, I use Python 3, but I may be forced to use Python 2 (part of a legacy system) in the future.

Comment: `iseof`, maybe...

Comment: You could use `readLines` and get them all as a list. That way you know exactly what you've got at any point based on the index and the length as you iterate. Function name: maybe `eofnext()`?

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140281/how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-is-at-its-eof)

Comment: Compare file length to current position?

Comment: For sake of clarification, say your file has three lines. Would it read a line and do its action three times, then do the _"some action just before that happens"_ ... or would it read a line and do something two times, do the _"some action just before that happens"_, then read the final line and do its action?

Comment: To clarify (I hope): What I had in mind was to detect whether or not there was any more data at all in the file---any number of bytes (my proposed solution answers that question--I think--but the point is to see if others have a better way), _before_ an external process shuts me out, because that other process stops _after_ it finds out that EOF has occurred. My process needs to know that EOF is _about_ to occur so that it can take some associated action.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f.tell()` to find out your current position in the file.

The problem is, that you need to find out how big the file is.
The niave (and efficient) solution is `os.path.getsize(filepath)` and compare that to the result of `tell()` but that will return the size in bytes, which is only relavent if reading in binary mode (`'rb'`) as your file may have multi-byte characters.

Your best solution is to seek to the end and back to find out the size.

```
def char_count(f):
    current = f.tell()
    f.seek(0, 2)
    end = f.tell()
    f.seek(current)
    return end

def chars_left(f, length=None):
    if not length:
        length = char_count(f)
    return length - f.tell()
```

Preferably, run `char_count` once at the beginning, and then pass that into chars_left.  Seeking isn't efficient, but you need to know how long your file is in characters and the only way is by reading it.

If you are reading line by line, and want to know before reading the last line, you also have to know how long your last line is to see if you are at the beginning of the last line.
If you are reading line by line, and only want to know if the next line read will result in an EOF, then when `chars_left(f, total) == 0` you know you are there (no more lines left to read)

Answer (score 0):

I've formulated this code to avoid the use of `tell` (perhaps using `tell` is simpler):

```
import os

class NearEOFException(Exception): pass  

def tellMe_before_EOF(filePath, chunk_size):
    fileSize = os.path.getsize(filePath)
    chunks_num = (fileSize // chunk_size)    # how many chunks can we read from file?
    reads = 0                               # how many chunks we read so far

    f = open(filePath)

    if chunks_num == 0:
        raise NearEOFException("File is near EOF")

    for i in range(chunks_num-1):
        yield f.read(chunk_size)
    else:
        raise NearEOFException("File is near EOF")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = tellMe_before_EOF("xyz", 3)   # read in chunks of 3 chars
    while True:
        print(next(g), end='')       # near EOF raise NearEOFException
```

The naming of the function is disputed. It's boring to name things, I'm just not good at that.

The function works like this: take the size of the file and see approximately how many times can we read N sized chunks and store it in `chunks_num`. This simple division gets us near EOF, the question is where do you think near EOF is? Near the last char for example or near the last nth characters? Maybe that's something to keep in mind if it matters.

Trace through this code to see how it works.

Comment: I acknowledge the increased utility you are proposing. See my earlier clarification.

Comment: Is `ftell` bad? Please provide reference or explanation as to why you avoid using it.

Comment: @MMM My code doesn't suggest that `tell` is bad. I'm only providing another coding alternative. Using `tell`  is perhaps simpler.