# While(!EOF()) equivalent in Python

Tags: python, loops

I'm working on a school project and it specifically asks for a while not end-of-file loop which I don't know how to do in Python. I'm taking in user input (not from an external file) and computing some math in this infinite loop until they CTRL+C to break the loop. Any thoughts would really help me out. I've added part of the instruction if that helps clarify. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out whether a file is at its \`eof\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140281/how-to-find-out-whether-a-file-is-at-its-eof)

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is supposed to stop on two conditions:

- An illegal value was entered, ie some value that couldn't be converted to a `float`. In this case, a `ValueError` will be raised.
- You entered `ctrl-Z`, which means an EOF. (Sorry, having no Windows here, I just tested it on Linux, where I think that `ctrl-D` is the equivalent of the Windows `ctrl-Z`). An `EOFError` will be raised.

So, you should just create an infinite loop, and break out of it when one of these exceptions occur.

I separated the handling of the exceptions so that you can see what happens and print some meaningful error message:

```
while True:
    try:
        amount = float(input())
        print(amount) # do your stuff here
    except ValueError as err:
        print('Terminating because', err)
        break
    except EOFError:
        print('EOF!')
        break
```

If you just want to quit without doing anything more, you can handle both exceptions the same way:

```
while True:
    try:
        amount = float(input())
        print(amount) # do your stuff here
    except (ValueError, EOFError):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:-

```
while True:
    amount = raw_input("Dollar Amount: ")
    try:
        amount = float(amount)
        # do your calculation with amount
        # as per your needs here

    except ValueError:
        print 'Cannot parse'
        break
```

Comment: Hi @Chrisz, kindly check his link for reference, he needs input from user and then process it accordingly. There was no need to open or read a file as per description on the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEy73.jpg

Comment: End of file won't result in `ValueError`.

Comment: it is not `ValueError`, but `EOFError`