# Python - grab lines from text file, lines x-y

Tags: python

The way to grab the first 10 lines of a text file could be done this way:

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
        lines = [next(myfile).strip() for x in xrange(10)]
```

This will print the first 10 lines

But what if I only wanted lines 5-10? How would I do that?
The file isn't small, it's going to be big. I need an efficient way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read file N lines at a time in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832856/how-to-read-file-n-lines-at-a-time-in-python)

Comment: Yep, the `islice` solution from that question is the way to go, imo: `lines = [line.strip() for line in islice(myfile, 5, 11)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the easiest way to do this is with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
with open('myfile.text') as f:
    lines = islice(f, 5, 11)
```

The nice part about this is that it won't ever load the entire file; it'll do only as much work as it needs to.

Note that the functions in `itertools` are lazy, so you need to either finish working with the lines *before* you close the file, or wrap the `islice` in a `list()` to force evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

How about slicing the list that you already have.

```
with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
    lines = [next(myfile).strip() for x in xrange(10)][5:10]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know where you want to start just change the range in the for loop for example.

```
var1 = 5
var2 = 10
for x in range(var1, var2):
```

would loop from 5 to 10, of course you can tweak your variables further.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
>>> with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
>>>  lines = myfile.read().split('\n')[5:10]
```

Split will separate it line by line into an array of lines, and the [5:10] will return array elements from 5 to 10, the variable "lines" will be an array, however, so to just get a string of lines 5 to 10, you could:

```
>>> with open("myfile.txt") as myfile:
>>>  lines = '\n'.join(myfile.read().split('\n')[5:10])
```

The only difference here, is the '\n'.join() part, which just takes each element of the array of lines, and joins them into a string seperated by a newline.

Comment: Missing small point here. File has no operation split.
So we have read the content and then split and cut the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Reads the file and takes lines x to y as a list to content variable:

```
with open('content.txt') as f:
    content=f.read().split('\n')[x-1:y]
```

Take care of '\n' and '\r\n'.