# How to divide two large numpy matrix elemtwise without getting killed?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two matrices A,B  both of shape 150000 X 150000

I want to divide each element of A with each element of B, element wise.
The way I currently do it is -

```
res=A/B
```

I do get the output for small matrices, but for large matrices as mine. The process gets killed. Any suggestions on how to do this efficiently ?

sample data

```
A =
[
[2.2,3.3,4.4]
[2.2,3.3,4.4]
[2.2,3.3,4.4]]

B=
[
[1,3.3,4.4]
[2.2,1,4.4]
[2.2,3.3,1]]

res = 
[
[2.2,1,1]
[1,3.3,1]
[1,1,4.4]]
```

This is a 3 X 3 matrix, I'm working with 150000 X 150000 matrix

Comment: You would need at least > 167GB of RAM (float64) just for storing the result. Double that for the second division argument. If you don't have that, you can't do it without out-of-memory computing [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20external%20memory%20algorithms,computer's%20main%20memory%20at%20once.&text=External%20memory%20algorithms%20are%20analyzed%20in%20the%20external%20memory%20model.) which is not in numpy's world anymore.

Comment: I do have an additional ram of upto 200GB. Can you let me know how exactly you came up with the mem requirements?

Comment: 150000^2 * 8 byte (float64) for a single matrix. If you do in-place division (if allowed) you would need two of those (A and B) to compute in-place storing in res: `res <-> A /= B`. (Meaning: 200GB is not enough)

Comment: If `A` is sparse, you can use `scipy.sparse` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html package. But I suppose `B` can't contain any zeros. So you will still need at least the 167GB to store the dense `B` as @Neo mentioned.

Comment: Well you can just read it line by line and write the results line by line. Since you are talking about element wise computations. Use two chunk readers to get A and B and write the result using a third one. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727412/efficient-way-to-partially-read-large-numpy-file/42727761) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067406/how-to-read-a-super-huge-file-into-numpy-array-n-lines-at-a-time).

Comment: @sascha What did you mean by "not in numpy's world anymore"?   AFAICS `numpy.memmap` is alive and well (I see no deprecation notices) so this question may well be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803

Answer (score 1):

you could try to use pandas and set the type of the values to something small memory wise, or at least check the memory allocated for a value, usually Python uses float64 or so, which is in some cases way too much.

use

```
pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
```

or

```
pd.to_numeric(column, downcast='integer')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he is using `numpy`, not python lists.  `pandas`'s dtypes are based on `numpy`.  But changing the dtype, say from a default `float64` to 32 only cuts memory usage in half.  `pandas` has a lot of overhead compared to `numpy` (e.g. row and column indices).

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is a limitation on memory allocation (i.e. you have enough RAM for `A` and `B`, but not enough for `A`, `B` and `res` all together) then in-place division `/=` will do the job in the memory space already allocated for `A` without having to allocate memory for a new array `res`.  Of course, you'll overwrite the original content of `A` in the process:

```
A /= B
```

But if you end up needing to use arrays that are too large to fit in RAM then you should explore the use of `numpy.memmap` which is designed for this purpose. See for example [Working with big data in python and numpy, not enough ram, how to save partial results on disc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149803)

Comment: But `/=` still has to create a temporary buffer.  There is a `np.divide.at` that does unbuffered division, but these `at` methods are more useful for dealing with repeated indices than reducing memory use.

Comment: @hpaulj I’m surprised to learn about the buffering. Is it not still the case that `A/=B` requires (at least) one fewer large allocations than `res=A/B`?