# how to read 10 records every time from csv in python or pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a csv file with a 100,000 rows and I want to read 10 rows at a time and process each row to save to its respective file every time and sleep for 5 seconds. 
I'm trying Nslice but it only reads the first 10 and stops.
I want the program to run till the EOF. I'm using jupyter, python2 & pyspark if thats of any help.

```
from itertools import islice
with open("per-vehicle-records-2020-01-31.csv") as f:
    while True:
        next_n_lines = list(islice(f, 10))
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        else:
            print(next_n_lines)
            sleep(5)
```

this does not separate each row. It combines 10 rows into a list

```
['"cosit","year","month","day","hour","minute","second","millisecond","minuteofday","lane","lanename","straddlelane","straddlelanename","class","classname","length","headway","gap","speed","weight","temperature","duration","validitycode","numberofaxles","axleweights","axlespacings"\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","2","0","90","1","Test1","0","","5","HGV_RIG","11.4","2.88","3.24","70.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","3","0","90","2","Test2","0","","2","CAR","5.2","3.17","2.92","71.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","5","0","90","1","Test1","0","","2","CAR","5.1","2.85","2.51","70.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","6","0","90","2","Test2","0","","2","CAR","5.1","3.0","2.94","69.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","9","0","90","1","Test1","0","","5","HGV_RIG","11.5","3.45","3.74","70.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","10","0","90","2","Test2","0","","2","CAR","5.4","3.32","3.43","71.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","13","0","90","2","Test2","0","","2","CAR","5.3","3.19","3.23","71.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","13","0","90","1","Test1","0","","2","CAR","5.2","3.45","3.21","70.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n', '"000000000997","2020","1","31","1","30","16","0","90","1","Test1","0","","5","HGV_RIG","11.0","2.9","3.13","69.0","0.0","0.0","0","0","0","",""\n']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: tried using nslice and normal read. nslice gives me a list of the rows combine which is not good.

Comment: i need 10 rows at a time. in the same list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
path_data = 'per-vehicle-records-2020-01-31.csv'

reader = pd.read_csv(path_data, sep=';', chunksize=10, iterator=True)
for i in reader:
    df = next(reader)
    print(df)
    time.sleep(5)
```

The chunksize will read every 10 rows, and the for loop should make sure they are read in that manner, and sleep 5 seconds in between each iteration.

Comment: this worked with just one tweak. this started printing from 10. i had to print 'i' and then continue as stated thanks :)

Comment: if u have a fix for the that small tweak, it would be a life save. :))

Comment: @KushSingh Just add print(i) before df = next(reader)

Answer (score 0):

[islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) retrun a genrator so you need o iterate after you assign it

```
from itertools import islice
with open("per-vehicle-records-2020-01-31.csv") as f:
    while True:
        next_n_lines = islice(f, 10)
        if not next_n_lines:
            break
        else:
            for line in next_n_lines:
               print(line)
            sleep(5)
```

you read more here [How to read file N lines at a time in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832856/how-to-read-file-n-lines-at-a-time-in-python)

Comment: yes, I did read it. The issue is the whole 10 rows are combined to a list. I want it as a list of 10 rows separate or nested.

Comment: but you have 10 row in the list for each iteration it's the same

Comment: thats 10 rows combined into a single list. is there a way to get a list with 10 rows

Comment: sorry  please clarify i don't understand what you want please show me input output