# python - read from file and assign into multiple lists

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, readline

How do I make the code so it reads the file and splits it so that it can assign which lines I specify into a certain named list.
I want the first 3 lines to be assigned into a list then the next 3 and so on, so it would be:

list1 = Steve, Cat, v, 2, 3, 4, 1, 28

list2 = John, Dog, h , 6, 1, 7, 2, 45

list3 = (something)

text file below named character:

```
Steve
Cat
v 2 3 4 1 28
John
Dog
h 6 1 7 2 45
```

main code below

```
character_file = open("character.txt", 'r')
character_list = character_file.readlines()

for character in character_list:
    print(character)
    character_list_split = character.split()

    Steve = character_list_split[0,2]
    John = character_list_split[3,5]
    
character_file.close()

print(Steve)
print(John)
```

Thanks for the help I'm new to python

Comment: Is it always three lines? like first line is first name, 2nd line is last name, and 3rd line is attributes something like that?

Comment: yeah it's always 3 lines

Comment: Try to use `with open("character.txt", 'r') as character_file:` instead of `open()` and then `close`. It will close the file even if there's an exception.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, using a `with` block will close the file automatically once it goes out of scope.

This solution grabs your lines in blocks of 3.  It then places the lists into a dictionary with the name as the key.  It's not practical to put the lists into variables with the names as you have done.

```
with open("character.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    names = {}
    for i in range(0, len(lines), 3):
        name = lines[i].strip()
        names[name] = [name, lines[i+1].strip()] + \
            lines[i+2].strip().split(' ')
```

As S3DEV has kindly mentioned in the comments, this is not very effective for large files and the `file` object itself can be iterated rather than reading in the entire file with `readlines()`.  I've taken a shortcut and assumed that your file will always have 3 lines for each grouping and that your file will not end in the middle of an entry.

```
with open("character.txt", 'r') as f:
    names = {}
    while name := f.readline().strip():
        petname = f.readline().strip()
        information = f.readline().strip().split(' ')
        names[name] = [name, petname] + information
```

(note: walrus operator `:=` requires Python 3.8 or above)

Comment: If reading a large file, the answer could be made more efficient by using a counter, rather than reading the entire file into memory.  `f` can be iterated directly, thus removing the need to read the entire file into memory.

Comment: I wonder where `readlines` is still taught. In my opinion it should have been deprecated and thrown away when Python 3 was developed.

Comment: I don't do much in the way of reading raw files anymore (csvs with Pandas and binary into NumPy, spoiled I know!).  I'm assuming you mean using readline from f directly, but if I turn f into an iterator, there's no inherent way to just grab 3 off the top short of inslice that I found.

Comment: @S3DEV Is that edit more in line with what you had in mind? (doing this more for my own edification at this point)

Comment: @jonsca - Even more simple actually.  Something along the lines of the *first* solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5832971/6340496).

Comment: @S3DEV Ah, so my instinct about ´islice´ (made a typo above) was correct.  My search-Fu obviously failed me on finding the linked question.